# angular onblur works incorrectly when clicking input in div

Tags: javascript, angular, input, onblur, onfocus

I'm giving a tabindex to the div and closing the div with on blur but when I click on the input inside the div, the div closes. How can I solve this?

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="openToggle('toggle1')">Toggle 1</button>
<button (click)="openToggle('toggle2')">Toggle 2</button>

<div
  *ngIf="selectedToggle === 'toggle1'"
  tabindex="0"
  (blur)="closeToggle()"
  class="menu"
>
  Toggle 1
</div>

<div
  *ngIf="selectedToggle === 'toggle2'"
  tabindex="1"
  (blur)="closeToggle()"
  class="menu"
>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
  public selectedToggle = '';

  public openToggle(e: string) {
    this.selectedToggle = e;
  }

  public closeToggle() {
    this.selectedToggle = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected, when you click in the input, the focus shift from the `div` to the `input` thus firing the `blur` event on the div.

Comment: thank you, but the input is in the div. I just want to close my div when click outside of the div. Now, when I click input in the div, the div closes. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You'll have to create a backdrop div for that. The blur event won't fit your needs here.